# Django filter query using future date-time

Tags: django, datetime, django-views

How do I filter a query to contain only the objects that have a date-time field that holds a DateTime in the future?
Here is my code that is not working:

```py
def matches(request):
    matches= Match.objects.all().filter(match_date_time > timezone.now() )
    context = {'matches': matches}
    return render(request, 'bookie/matches.html', context)
```

`match_date_time` is a model field in the `Match` model but I get an error that it's not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [**`__gt`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt) to filter with *greater than*:

```
def matches(request):
    matches = Match.objects.filter(match_date_time__gt=timezone.now())
    return render(request, 'bookie/matches.html', {'matches': matches})
```

Comment: Do you mind checking this one out too? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74594526/12601926